# How to create these boxes with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

If I go to this website https://www.odesk.com/ and scroll down a little bit, there are some boxes just below "Find talented freelances ready" and I was wondering how I would create these using CSS?

Also on the website http://www.lynda.com/ there are some nice boxes that flip on hover, and I was wondering if there was anyway to recreate these too.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: The flip effect is achieved with CSS transformation. Google "CSS flip animation", it's pretty easy to implement.

Comment: You're looking for someone to do it for you...not for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For the flip animation:

You have to create four divs: two to hold the whole thing, one which is the front, and holds the contents for when the front is showing, and lastly the back one, which displays on hover.

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
<div class="flipper">

<!-- This is the front of the card, put your initial content here -->

    <div class="front">
        <h1>Hello</h1>      
    </div>

<!-- This is the back of the card, put the content to be displayed on flip here-->

    <div class="back">
        <h1>Hello again!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
perspective: 1000;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
   .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
width: 155px;
height: 150px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
backface-visibility: hidden;

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
border: 2px black solid;
text-align: center;
background-color: #76EE00;
z-index: 2;
/* for firefox 31 */
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    border: 2px black solid;
    text-align: center;
background-color: #66CD00;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/twuddn6f/

---

#### And the boxes on the other site...

And as a sidenote if your interested, here's the CSS from the site for the boxes.

**CSS**

```css
.oBtn {
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  padding: 5px 14px 3px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: always
}
.oBtn.isDisabled,
.oBtnDisabled,
.oBtn[disabled],
.oBtn.isDisabled:active,
.oBtnDisabled:active,
.oBtn[disabled]:active,
.oBtn.isDisabled:hover,
.oBtnDisabled:hover,
.oBtn[disabled]:hover {
  color: #a7a7a2;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0de;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #f0f0ee;
  cursor: default
}
.oBtn:hover {
  text-decoration: none
}
.oBtnPrimary {
  color: white;
  background: #7bd454;
  background: #7bd454 -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7bd454, #62c831 95%, #53bf29);
  background: #7bd454 -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7bd454, #62c831 95%, #53bf29);
  background: #7bd454 -o-linear-gradient(top, #7bd454, #62c831 95%, #53bf29);
  background: #7bd454 linear-gradient(top, #7bd454, #62c831 95%, #53bf29);
  border: 1px solid #509e19;
  border-bottom-color: #198d0f;
  border-top-color: #6dbe38;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(38, 151, 72, 0.5), inset 0 1px 0 #9fe662;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(38, 151, 72, 0.5), inset 0 1px 0 #9fe662;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(38, 151, 72, 0.5), inset 0 1px 0 #9fe662;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #25a811
}
.oBtnPrimary:hover {
  background: #93dd64;
  background: #93dd64 -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #93dd64, #72d239 95%, #6fcc37);
  background: #93dd64 -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93dd64, #72d239 95%, #6fcc37);
  background: #93dd64 -o-linear-gradient(top, #93dd64, #72d239 95%, #6fcc37);
  background: #93dd64 -ms-linear-gradient(top, #93dd64, #72d239 95%, #6fcc37);
  background: #93dd64 linear-gradient(top, #93dd64, #72d239 95%, #6fcc37);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(38, 151, 72, 0.5), inset 0 1px 0 #9fe662;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(38, 151, 72, 0.5), inset 0 1px 0 #9fe662;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(38, 151, 72, 0.5), inset 0 1px 0 #9fe662;
  border: 1px solid #6dbe38;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #198d0f;
  color: white
}
.oBtnPrimary:active {
  background: #6ec54f;
  background: #6ec54f -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6ec54f, #56b92d);
  background: #6ec54f -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6ec54f, #56b92d);
  background: #6ec54f -o-linear-gradient(top, #6ec54f, #56b92d);
  background: #6ec54f -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6ec54f, #56b92d);
  background: #6ec54f linear-gradient(top, #6ec54f, #56b92d);
  border: 1px solid #239365;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: white
}
.oBtnPrimary:visited {
  color: white
}
.oBtnPrimaryBlue {
  background: #00aaec;
  background: #00aaec -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00aaec, #00a7ec 95%, #0096e8);
  background: #00aaec -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00aaec, #00a7ec 95%, #0096e8);
  background: #00aaec -o-linear-gradient(top, #00aaec, #00a7ec 95%, #0096e8);
  background: #00aaec linear-gradient(top, #00aaec, #00a7ec 95%, #0096e8);
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #007de8;
  border-bottom-color: #1d60dd;
  border-top-color: #0a81d4;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(15, 59, 141, 0.31), inset 0 1px 0 #00c1f0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(15, 59, 141, 0.31), inset 0 1px 0 #00c1f0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(15, 59, 141, 0.31), inset 0 1px 0 #00c1f0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #0069de
}
.oBtnPrimaryBlue:hover {
  background: #00b6ee;
  background: #00b6ee -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00b6ee, #00b0ee 95%, #00a1eb);
  background: #00b6ee -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00b6ee, #00b0ee 95%, #00a1eb);
  background: #00b6ee -o-linear-gradient(top, #00b6ee, #00b0ee 95%, #00a1eb);
  background: #00b6ee -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00b6ee, #00b0ee 95%, #00a1eb);
  background: #00b6ee linear-gradient(top, #00b6ee, #00b0ee 95%, #00a1eb);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(15, 59, 141, 0.31), inset 0 1px 0 #00c1f0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(15, 59, 141, 0.31), inset 0 1px 0 #00c1f0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(15, 59, 141, 0.31), inset 0 1px 0 #00c1f0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #0069de;
  border: 1px solid #007de8;
  border-bottom-color: #1d60dd;
  border-top-color: #0a81d4;
  color: white
}
.oBtnPrimaryBlue:active {
  background: #1a9fec;
  background: #1a9fec -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1a9fec, #1a9fec);
  background: #1a9fec -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1a9fec, #1a9fec);
  background: #1a9fec -o-linear-gradient(top, #1a9fec, #1a9fec);
  background: #1a9fec -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1a9fec, #1a9fec);
  background: #1a9fec linear-gradient(top, #1a9fec, #1a9fec);
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #156ee8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none
}
.oBtnPrimaryBlue:visited {
  color: white
}
.oBtnSecondary {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #80807c;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #f4f4f2), color-stop(100%, #e5e5e3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f4f4f2, #e5e5e3);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f2, #e5e5e3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f2, #e5e5e3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f2, #e5e5e3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-bottom-color: #b7b7b7;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(204, 202, 202, 0.51), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(229, 228, 228, 0.51);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(128, 128, 124, 0.1);
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  *vertical-align: auto;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline
}
.oBtnSecondary:hover {
  color: #80807c;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #f8f8f7), color-stop(100%, #ededec));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f8f8f7, #ededec);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f8f8f7, #ededec);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f8f8f7, #ededec);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f8f8f7, #ededec);
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d4;
  border-bottom-color: #bdbdba;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(204, 202, 202, 0.51), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(229, 228, 228, 0.51);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(128, 128, 124, 0.1)
}
.oBtnSecondary:active {
  color: #80807c;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #d2d2d0), color-stop(100%, #dddddc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, #d2d2d0 0, #dddddc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #d2d2d0 0, #dddddc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, #d2d2d0 0, #dddddc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(center top, #d2d2d0 0, #dddddc);
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d0;
  border-top-color: #b9b9b6;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.4) inset;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white
}
.oBtnSecondary:visited {
  color: #80807c
}
.oBtnSecondary.oDisabled,
.oBtnSecondary[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: .5
}
.oBtnSecondary.oDisabled:hover,
.oBtnSecondary.oDisabled.active,
.oBtnSecondary.oDisabled.visited,
.oBtnSecondary[disabled]:hover,
.oBtnSecondary[disabled].active,
.oBtnSecondary[disabled].visited {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #f4f4f2), color-stop(100%, #e5e5e3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f4f4f2, #e5e5e3);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f2, #e5e5e3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f2, #e5e5e3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f2, #e5e5e3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(204, 202, 202, 0.51), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(229, 228, 228, 0.51);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(128, 128, 124, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-bottom-color: #b7b7b7
}
.oBtnPrimary,
.oBtnSecondary,
.oBtnTertiary,
.oBtnPrimaryBlue,
.oBtnPrimaryGradient,
.oBtnBlueGradient {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center
}
.oBtnTertiary {
  color: #00afef;
  background: transparent;
  border: none
}
.oBtnTertiary:hover {
  color: #006489
}
.oBtnTertiary:active {
  color: #383838
}
.oBtnPrimaryGradient {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, color-stop(0%, #68b339), color-stop(49%, #68b339), color-stop(51%, #5ea32b));
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #68b339 0, #68b339 49%, #5ea32b 51%, #5ea32b 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68b339 0, #68b339 49%, #5ea32b 51%, #5ea32b 100%);
  font-size: frompx(18);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 1px .99px .01px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: white
}
.oBtnPrimaryGradient:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, color-stop(0%, #5eaa2c), color-stop(49%, #5eaa2c), color-stop(51%, #51991a));
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5eaa2c 0, #5eaa2c 49%, #51991a 51%, #51991a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5eaa2c 0, #5eaa2c 49%, #51991a 51%, #51991a 100%);
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white
}
.oBtnPrimary:not(#postJob):not(#findJob) {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #30bcf2), color-stop(49%, #30bcf2), color-stop(51%, #00adef), color-stop(100%, #00adef));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #30bcf2 0, #30bcf2 49%, #00adef 51%, #00adef 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #30bcf2 0, #30bcf2 49%, #00adef 51%, #00adef 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #30bcf2 0, #30bcf2 49%, #00adef 51%, #00adef 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30bcf2 0, #30bcf2 49%, #00adef 51%, #00adef 100%);
  font-size: frompx(18);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 1px .99px .01px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: white
}
.oBtnPrimary:not(#postJob):not(#findJob):hover {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #30b1e2), color-stop(49%, #30b1e2), color-stop(51%, #009fdb), color-stop(100%, #009fdb));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #30b1e2 0, #30b1e2 49%, #009fdb 51%, #009fdb 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #30b1e2 0, #30b1e2 49%, #009fdb 51%, #009fdb 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #30b1e2 0, #30b1e2 49%, #009fdb 51%, #009fdb 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30b1e2 0, #30b1e2 49%, #009fdb 51%, #009fdb 100%);
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer
}
.oBtnPrimary:not(#postJob):not(#findJob):visited {
  color: white
}
.oBtnSecondary:not(.oPageBtn):not(.oButton) {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
  color: #00adef;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 4px solid #e2e2e2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px 10px
}
.oBtnSecondary:not(.oPageBtn):not(.oButton):hover,
.oBtnSecondary:not(.oPageBtn):not(.oButton):visited {
  color: #00adef
}
.oMed {
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
  margin: 5px 0
}

And the HTML...
```

```html
<a class="oBtn oBtnPrimary" href="#" id="findJob">Want a job? Sign up!</a>
<a class="oBtn oBtnPrimary oBtnPrimaryBlue" href="#" id="postJob">Want to hire? Post a job!</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/twuddn6f/1/

Comment: This just seems to be a code dump without any explanation as to what does what.  Moreover, your fiddle is empty.

Comment: Very sorry, I will try and fix, I was just trying to provide a little bit of help

Comment: A wall of code without comments, just copied directly from the website, doesn't offer any help.  While there is the fastest gun in the west problem, this kind of answer will usually only get downvotes.  In regards to the FGITW problem, you could have done a minimal example while still maintaining speed.

Comment: Also, if you're going to post html, you'd get a better reception if it actually addressed the question.(eg, the stack snippets show buttons, but don't address the question of the boxes listed)

Comment: Ok thank you everyone, I will try to clean up the code and do some explaining :)

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, your second example doesn't replicate the boxes on the other site.  It replicates buttons, but not the boxes under the noted header.